# Como executar uma função do javascript no lado servidor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

No lado servidor:

```
return JavaScript("Callback()");
```

No lado cliente:

```
function Callback(){
  //
}
```

O resultado é exibido como "Callback()" na página da web, peguei o exemplo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12508307/6647038).

Alguma solução ?

Comment: JavaScript não interage diretamente com back-end e front-end, ou roda no front-end ou roda no back-end (com interpretadores como node.js ou semelhantes), nunca vai ser possivel comunicação direta, **WEB é HTTP**, ou seja é requisição e resposta, contendo payload (POST, PUT) ou não.... O que exatamente você quer fazer? Porque existem soluções estratégicas para cada caso que podem lhe atender, mas o principal é entender o que é HTTP, não só ouvi falar, mas entender mesmo, para trabalhar com WEB e APIs REST.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento essa é a ideia: O site manda um e-mail para confirmação da conta, após de clicar um botão "confirmar", redireciona para página principal e mostrar um modal dizendo que foi confirmado sucesso. Eu não quero criar outra view ou uma página html  dizendo que foi confirmada, eu quero apenas mostrar um modal.

Comment: Pode usar uma sessão para dizer que foi enviado ou pode usar o parametro da querystring para com uma IF informar a View que deve exibir o modal na pagina seguinte.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento porque eu não pensei nisso ? Que raiva , obrigado.

Comment: Imagina, uma boa noite o/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento igualmente 